# Get Row Values From SqlException

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, exception

I'm saving a DataTable(dt) to database table(tblCountry) using bulkcopy. There are constraints set for tblCountry , so exceptions throw up if there is a mistake in dt.
For eg: tblCountry has CountryId as the Primary Key. If dt has 2 records with same CountryId, that would throw an exception.

Is it possible to get that CountryId which is a duplicate, when there is an exception. 
With C# or maybe Stored Procedure SqlServer 2008..

```
protected void btnSave_Click()    
{    
  try
    {
      conn.Open();
      SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn);
      bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "tblCountry";
      bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(0, 1);
      bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(1, 2);
      bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dt);
      conn.Close();    
    }    
   Catch(SqlException ex)    
    {    
      throw ex;    
    }    
}
```

Comment: When it has duplicate `CountryId`, does it have all the column values same for the rows?

Comment: ok, I am not aware of the way to get the row that generated error but yes you can correct table entries before doing bulkcopy